# How do I switch to Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-environments, software-installation

I'd like to use `Xubuntu` in 11.10 instead of Unity, how do I install it and switch to it?

Comment: If you want to also get rid of any "ubuntu gnomish" cruft, try psychocat's [Pure XFCE](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexfce)

Comment: Check On http://codetalk2.blogspot.in/2015/02/transform-ubuntu-into-xubuntu.html

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Instructions for 11.10 and 12.04

Install the `xubuntu-desktop` package - to do that, run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

At some point during the install, you will be asked to choose between `gdm` and `lightdm` - I prefer `lightdm`, so thats what the screenshot shows.

Logout, you will be confronted by the LightDM manager.

Then, click the little cog wheel, and select `Xubuntu Session`.

Then, enter your password, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you'll be logged into Xubuntu.

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between **lightdm** and **gdm**?

Comment: @Alvar `lightdm` is installed by default, and (in my opinion) is prettier than `gdm` - `lightdm` is also easier on ram, CPU etc than `gdm`

Comment: What's the difference between Xfce session and Xubuntu session? I thought Xubuntu was Ubuntu using Xfce!

Comment: @Poldie XFCE is plain XFCE, Xubuntu is XFCE, but with some added tweaks to the config to make it "Xubuntu'ed".

Comment: Ok I'll start using Xubuntu Session tonight - thanks!

Comment: Do these still work for 13.04 and newer? Also, it is my opinion you should use `dist-upgrade`, since `upgrade` alone won't clean everything up.

Answer (score 13):

or use [tasksel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel)

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel
```

Check xubuntu and uncheck ubuntu.

Comment: tasksel is the best tool

Answer (score 0):

And to remove original gnome desktop (after jrg's how-to) remove the package `ubuntu-desktop`

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
```

You also sould do `apt-get autoremove` after doing that:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Removing gnome desktop isn't a good idea, it removes a lot of stuff that `xubuntu-desktop` needs as well.

Comment: Sure? I didn't read something like this.

Comment: @jrg If `xubuntu-desktop` needs it, it should be listed as a dependency and won't get autoremoved.