# How to install XFCE in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, xfce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I switch to Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64241/how-do-i-switch-to-xubuntu)

Any ideas how to install XFCE in 11.10? I don't want Unity or Gnome 3, but the xubuntu dektop seems to be not available in Ubuntu 11.10
Jeannie