# How do I install XFCE so I can choose it as the desktop environment at login?

Tags: 11.10, xfce, desktop-environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I switch to Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64241/how-do-i-switch-to-xubuntu)

I am currently running the vanilla Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop. At first I liked the Unity desktop (the previous version I used was 10.04 LTS) and thought that I could live with it. But after about a week of usage, I can feel that it's causing some really annoying lags. So I switched to Unity 2D.

The performance was a little better but still, the system lags. Now I want to install XFCE and use it as my desktop environment. I was thinking that installing `xubuntu-desktop` would be able to do the job but I am afraid it will overwrite the unity desktop (which I still want to keep).

So basically I am asking how to install XFCE so that it will be an option in the DE at the login screen?

Comment: Why do you want to keep Unity, if you no longer think you can live with it?? All in all, it's probably best to do a clean install of Xubuntu.

Comment: @mikewhatever I want to keep Unity so I can use it once in a while.