# Xubuntu still booting to Unity

Tags: xubuntu

I installed Xubuntu according to the accepted answer in this question; [How do I switch to Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64241/how-do-i-switch-to-xubuntu)

Now I get Xububtu startup and shutdown screens, but I still end up with Unity once it's booted.

I didn't get prompted to choose between lightdm and gdm and I don't seem to be getting the lightdm login screen.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the auto login feature ?

Turn it off and log out ;)

At the lightdm login screen you will then be able to select and log into xfce. I would guess you can then re-enable auto login.

Comment: I used the accepted answer to this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-with-lightdm to turn off auto login.

Answer (score 0):

At login you need to choose the kind of session you want to begin -- choose Xubuntu or xfce instead of Ubuntu. From then on the gdm should remember your last choice and use it as your default.

Answer (score 0):

If Auto login is enabled log out then when choosing the user to log in with prior to pressing enter after typing password click on Session then chose Xubuntu or XFe  for vanilla XFe.

auto login is not enabled just chose the same options from session when login in to ubuntu.