# What is the differences between XFCE session and Xubuntu session?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

Everytime I boot up Xubuntu, I get the question, XFCE session or Xubuntu session, what are the actual differences?

Comment: I think OP's question relates to finding the Xfce session choice *within* a vanilla Xubuntu installation.

Comment: vasa, no I know where it is, the differences with the options.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/91380/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntuxfce-and-xubuntu?lq=1

Comment: foss, it isn't.

Answer (score 11):

XFCE sessions offers a vanilla default XFCE layout (wallpaper, theme etc.) and Xubuntu session a personalized one. Menu are also slightly different. 
A suggestion : try both of them!

XFCE session:

[image: XFCE]

Xubuntu session:

[image: Xubuntu]

Comment: I never had that...

Comment: @BaileyRowland What you mean?

Comment: I just logged off from Kubuntu session and into KCFE session, It looks just like Kubuntu session. NO changes in anything i can see.

Comment: Why are you now talking about Kubuntu and KCFE (whatever that is) ???

Comment: @BaileyRowland I didn't spoked  about [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) and [LFCE](http://www.lfce.fr/)...

Comment: OMG oops! xubuntu! Confused me.

Comment: My Xubuntu Session and XFCE sessions look identical.  I customized Xubuntu, and (installation from a couple weeks back), and I just saw the XFCE session option for the first time, logged into it, and it has all my customizations still - looks no different.

Comment: You are not seeing a difference in the sessions because it sets up the configuration on first login and reuses it in future sessions: so it only matters which one you do first. The article suggests creating different accounts but I think it would be easier to delete the configuration files and re-login. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2105703&s=9c5ea9419ac76c4906700c9db0944fe6&p=12459424#post12459424

Answer (score 1):

Xfce is available on other distros outside of Ubuntu. There are no major "apparent" differences aside from branding options. However using Xubuntu implies the ubuntu core files and packages are standard. You could run Xubuntu with different file managers etc but essentially then you are really just modifying XFCE.