# Should I download Ubuntu and install Xfce on it or download Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, dell-vostro

I have laptop with 4GB RAM. Would it be better to get Ubuntu and then install Xfce on it, or to get Xubuntu?

Comment: Do not know what is happening with this question, but be better to download Xubuntu.  Will give a cleaner system.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with running a cleaner operating system.

Comment: It depends on your requirements - we only have a bit of a hint about your RAM, so if you can [edit] this to explain your doubts, that would probably help. But in general the benefits of using a flavor like Xubuntu over installing the corresponding DE in Ubuntu and/or [the differences between them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91380/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntuxfce-and-xubuntu) can be explained by experts; it's not purely a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Zanna There's also multiple things installing Xfce may mean. One way to get Xfce on an Ubuntu system without it is to install the `xubuntu-desktop` task or metapackage. People often mean or assume such a method. This seems to be the interpretation taken in most comments, and the answer, here. But as you say, there are other ways to install Xfce, which don't bring in as many packages. There are multiple other ways to do this; installing the lightweight `xfce4` metapackage is just one. Unfortunately I don't know most of the practical differences (especially as applied to the newest releases).

Comment: **Reviewers:** Consider before making an authoritative and dogmatic review decision that this question is opinion-based. Many Debian-based distributions such as Debian, Ubuntu, Mint and Elementary OS use either people's names or animal names to label their releases.This is because the distribution is supposed to work fine out of the box, and you can also completely customize it with the accompanying risk of a higher probability of unexpected results. It's sort of like the engineering dictum "If it ain't broke don't fix it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu uses animal names for release names not by accident. If you want a fossa install fossa. If you want to play Pokémon and evolve your own customized animals, Ubuntu is open source so you customize and configure it any way you want to. If you've decided to install Xfce, Xubuntu is offered as a convenience because everything you need to run the Xfce desktop environment works in Xubuntu out of the box, and it's better to run a cleaner operating system (native default Xfce in Xubuntu vs. installed Xfce in Ubuntu).