# How can I install XFCE along side Unity?

Tags: unity, xfce

I would like to be able to install XFCE to run alongside unity so I can choose, upon startup, which DE I use, without breaking any features of either DE.

Following this: [Xubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr: a classic beauty](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/xubuntu)

> Note: don't install Nautilus in Xubuntu! This will cause system
>   conflicts.

I don't want to affect ANY of the features in Unity, i.e. I want to be able to use the two interchangeably, so I can't follow some suggestions of just cleaning out all the old stuff as that would mean using Unity would be changed.

[Can I install Unity aside with XFCE and switch them as I want?](https://askubuntu.com/q/111400/65926) Is this possible in 12.04?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

There are no conflicts between XFCE and Unity, and Nautilus works perfectly fine on Xubuntu 12.04 and 12.10.

If you wish to install XFCE in Ubuntu, install either xubuntu-desktop (for XFCE + Xubuntu branding + all Xubuntu default apps), or just xfce by itself if you don't want to end up with two sets of default apps.

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Additionally - and I stress that this is based only on my own personal experience on one laptop - I've found that Xubuntu boots and runs much more quickly than Ubuntu whether Unity is installed or not. Based on this experience, I always prefer to install Unity on Xubuntu instead of XFCE on Ubuntu if I want an OS with both desktop environments. You may wish to try the same next time you reinstall your OS and see if you notice any performance improvements.

Comment: Thanks, this is on a desktop that runs most of the time so the latter isn't a problem, but certainly something I'l bare in mind for the future!

Comment: Afterwards, you may want to [restore the Unity greeter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/403477/restore-unity-greeter/550404).

Comment: Running this on your phone doesn't bring you any kind of convergence or desktop experience but apparently [**breaks your Ubuntu phone**](http://askubuntu.com/q/631698/40581). (This may change or this statement needs to be corrected when convergence is available on phones.)

Comment: I strongly recommend **not** installing just xfce4. It's missing a lot of integration and features you've come to expect from a desktop environment. I found `xfce4` almost unusable and nearly gave up on it...until I tried `xubuntu-desktop`, which includes a real task switcher/search box and other gnome-ish abilities.

Comment: Is it possible to have e.g. Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity as well as MATE-Desktop for e.g. xrdp? I am asking this since any kind of remote session usage with Unity / Pantheon / Gnome3 seems nigh to impossible...

Answer (score 8):

Just install `xubuntu-desktop` and it should work :). It should not conflict anything (never did for me).