# What is the best setup for my laptop?

Tags: system-installation

I have a Asus S56C here's an overview of my hardware tell me if you can help.

http://imageshack.us/a/img706/8903/p58r.png

I'm really sick of windows.

Answer (score 1):

All the hardware looks like it should run fine in Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.10.

If you are unsure why I mention these two versions:

**12.04** - Long term support, supported until April 2017. Best if you don't mind about being on the cutting edge with new features, but instead you want to not have to update every 6months-1year.

**13.10** - Current version, newest features are here. You will have to upgrade again by July 2014 as this is not long term supported.

I suggest 12.04 but that is a personal thing. The things that go wrong most often (in my experience) are wifi drivers because many vendors don't give linux updates.

Your best bet is to make a [Live USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) (with either 12.04 or 13.10, make sure you get the 64Bit version) and give Ubuntu a try. Check your wifi works, and then if you like it either set up a dual boot or wipe off windows and put on Ubuntu (You can install from this live USB)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an opinion based question but it looks like your hardware would work fine with Ubuntu. Make sure you do a backup of your machine just in case you want to put Windows back on. You should install a 64-bit version of Ubuntu because your computer is using 64-bit i7 architecture. The intel series processors perform just as well as AMD core in my opinion. The Solid State Drive will make the computer a lot faster. Ubuntu boots in just a couple of seconds on my SSD.

If you don't like Unity, the default window manager, you can install xfce which kind of looks like Windows. If you like the way the start menu has all of your stuff in it, then I would go with xfce. Xfce is super lightweight so it will run very quickly, but in my opinion it looks a little boring compared to Unity. Again, it's all your preference.

If you want to give it a try:

- [How can I install XFCE along side unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223536/how-can-i-install-xfce-along-side-unity)