# Is 1GB DDR2 RAM sufficient for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit desktop

Tags: ram

I have AMD processor with 1 GB DDR2 RAM. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop with 32 bit version. Many times when I open 3-4 applications, it hanged and need to restart my PC. Is it due to less RAM or other hardware?

Comment: It is, IMHO, of cause. I have an old netbook and 12.04 runs well for my needs, Unity and all.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you can run Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity on 1GB of RAM. It's not practical though. You should switch to a desktop environment that uses less memory. You should try [xfce](http://www.xfce.org/). It uses hardly any RAM compared to Unity and it has great performance on limited hardware.

- [How can I install XFCE along side unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223536/how-can-i-install-xfce-along-side-unity)

Comment: Thanks John. Should I need to uninstall Ubuntu?

Comment: John, what do you mean by `run Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity`? I am already using Ubuntu desktopp version.