# Restore Unity Greeter

Tags: unity, unity-greeter

I've installed **XFCE Desktop** environment, but when I decide to switch back to **Unity**, while uninstalling the `XFCE packages`, the `LightDM` keep starts like XFCE, and I want to restore the `Unity` one. I think that is called Unity Greeter. Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you take a picture so we could see exactly what you mean?

Answer (score 8):

I installed xubuntu-desktop on top of normal Ubuntu 14.04. Then I also noticed that the greeter had changed. I still use the xubuntu desktop, but I changed the greeter back by adding a line

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

into `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-xubuntu.conf`.

**Update:** Now on a new install of Ubuntu 14.10 + xubuntu-desktop on top of that, there is no directory `lightdm.conf.d` under `/etc/lightdm`. But [following advice from here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) I created the directory `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` and a file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf` with contents

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

and I get the unity greeter back.

Comment: This works on 16.04 too. Thanks!

Comment: works on 16.10 as well

Answer (score 7):

I didn't test it, but I suspect that @SampoSmolander might have the best approach.

Alternatively, I had success by removing the gtk greeter -- apparently this is what XFCE uses.

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

There still remains the tricky issue of getting rid of XFCE's mouse-themed greeter wallpaper:

- [How do I change the wallpaper of the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-of-the-login-creen)
- [How do I set the LightDM wallpaper in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449677/how-do-i-set-the-lightdm-wallpaper-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Note: It looks like multiple desktop environments install the lightdm-gtk-greeter package (including XFCE and MATE).  Interestingly, once you remove that package, the configuration files that @SampoSmolander discusses are no longer present.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. @SampoSmolander's answer might be the right way.

When using Ubuntu 14.04 you'll have to add the line

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

into `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf`

I [wrote a detailed how-to](http://alice-at-ubuntu.blogspot.hu/2015/01/login-screen-restore-to-default-from.html), but I don't know if it works, because LightDM reconfiguration seems to have solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

`cd /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d && sudo ln -s 50-unity-greeter.conf 99-unity-greeter.conf` and reboot the system.

The problem is caused by `lightdm-gtk-greeter` installing file called `60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` which overrides the unity greeter. I guess we should be able to just do `sudo update-alternatives --config lightdm-greeter` and select `unity-greeter` but `unity-greeter` package is incorrectly built and it does not support `update-alternatives`.

The above command workarounds the problem by creating a symbolic link with higher number so it can override the incorrect greeter selection. I'm using symbolic link to be better prepared for the future in case the file `50-unity-greeter.conf` is ever upgraded by system package.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Comment: I've tried that. Same login screen :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try enter this in the terminal, and it might fine this way I say:

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove lightdm
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

if this dos not work you could try enter again:

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

and it might work fine this way too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I lost the greeter on user switch.   The solution was in the package [light-locker](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-locker). Just reinstall, (or install if it was removed)

```
sudo apt-get install light-locker
```

In my case it was uninstalled, but the key is the package.

Answer (score 0):

To set the unity greeter as default, in Ubuntu 16.04 login screen, edit the file

```
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

and change the "greeter-session" line to "greeter-session=unity-greeter"