# Unity-greeter won't let me login

Tags: unity-greeter

… due some login problems. I just remove and reinstalled unity-greeter successfully, but now I cannot login in graphic mode with the default user I already had. Does anyone knows why is this happening or what can I do to fix this? A workaround in the web I found that changing the `autologin-user=mylocaluser` in `50-unity-greeter.conf` it would solve this issue but nothing worked.

In terminal mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) I can change users passwords but still I cannot login in graphic mode.

Comment: When you log in to the terminal using (Ctrl-Alt-F1). You can start the GUI by running the command `startx`
I just tried this on my VM but the problem is whether or not the HUD actually shows up... It seems that it doesn't for some reason. I know in other OSs like Raspbian if you use `startx` then It'll have its full DE pop up.

Comment: startx works but just gave me the ubuntu wallpaper only, no sidebar, no options at right upper corner...clicking the right mouse button I could "change" things but closing the all settings window the ubuntu wallpaper was the only thing I can have...any suggestions???

Comment: For more info about this, please log in on a virtual terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1), then switch back to grapical mode (Ctrl+Alt+F7 or F8) and try to log in. Switch back to virtual terminal and post the last lines of `/var/log/auth.log` that are related to your GUI log in attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the .Xauthority file from your home directory and reboot.
`rm .Xauthority`

Comment: Tobias, I did what you've said but nothing, I'm still inthe login screen...just said "Failed to start session" it didn't accepted the password I changed in Ctrl-Alt-F1 mode...any suggestions are welcome

Comment: It's definitely a . file or folder in your home directory, but which one I can't say for sure. You could temporarily moving all of them to a different folder.

Comment: if I move them all anywhere, what would the next step?? reboot?? all the files and folders belongs to the user I have...root and guest users not active

Comment: You can just move to another folder within your home directy, but yeah, reboot and try and login.

Comment: I moved them all including the hidden ones, but still can't login, do you think If I enable the root user would help???

Comment: That is very odd. And no, I don't think the root user will change anything. At this point I'd delete the user, make a new one and copy the files over.

Comment: I did it, but the issue remains...I don't wnat to format the HD for this...

Comment: If the issue persists across multiple users, the issue lies elsewhere. Could be to do with your desktop environment, or perhaps the unity-greeter config, I'd have a look at those.

Comment: where are those config files?? to send you over

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really know enough about that to help you, but I'm guessing you didn't fully restore unity-greeter, check out this thread perhaps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/403477/restore-unity-greeter
One of the answers suggests `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` that might help.

Comment: I did what you as you told, but nothing...after all that I reinstall 14.04.1; I couldn't find a solution...thanks a lot for your support

Comment: sorry I mistyped....I did as you told....that what I was trying to say