# How do I restore the default Ubuntu Unity 16.04 login screen?

Tags: unity, lightdm, login-screen

**Background:**

I wanted to change the wallpaper background of my Ubuntu Unity 16.04 login screen. I installed [lightdm-gtk-gtreeter-settings](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/08/20/change-login-screen-via-gtk-themes-ubuntu-16-04/) and only changed the wallpaper as shown below.

However, now my entire login screen looks different (similar to the one shown below).

**Screenshot:**

[image: Lightdm greeter settings]

[image: Lightdm login screen]

**Question:**

How do I restore the default Ubuntu Unity 16.04 login screen?

Comment: any help? http://askubuntu.com/a/470884/527764

Comment: @Zanna it helped, thanks a lot! Now I just need to find out why using [greeter background in 50-myconfig.conf](https://gist.github.com/orschiro/fa102fffd0824f2485ed4b376beb7352) doesn't change the wallpaper background.

Comment: hmm :S it's different in MATE so I can't investigate for you :(

Comment: That's alright. I will try to find a solution. Thanks!