# How do I change my boot animation back to the default after install of Lubuntu-desktop?

Tags: boot, plymouth

I am not talking about the login screen. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403477/restore-unity-greeter) has helped me fix that.

I am talking about the initial start up screen with incrementing anticipation dots during the boot. It says Lubuntu instead of Ubuntu. I'd like it to say Ubuntu if possible.

Where is this config file stored?

This is the screen I want to modify:

[image]

Comment: can u give a screenshot?

Comment: @ryanw screenshot for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change your boot screen, run the below command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

This will bring up a prompt where you can select which boot animation you want to use. Choose the `ubuntu-logo` entry, and hit Enter.

When you're done, update your system's cache using this command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Upon next boot, your boot animation will be back to normal.

<sup>[(source)](https://askubuntu.com/a/2292/208574)</sup>