# Wrong login dialog after meddling with xrdp and various desktops

Tags: unity, login-screen

After I've been meddling with xrdp for quite a while, trying mint, xfce4 and xubuntu as xrdp desktop environment, I have my login dialog changed to this. I can neither tell which desktop environment part it is nor what package should I remove or reinstall to fix it.

[image: wrong login dialog]

Comment: Regretfully, it didn't help.

Comment: What does `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` say?

Comment: /usr/sbin/lightdm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article helped: [Restore Unity Greeter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403477/restore-unity-greeter)

In short:

> Now on a new install of Ubuntu 14.10 + xubuntu-desktop on top of that, there is no directory lightdm.conf.d under /etc/lightdm. But following advice from here I created the directory /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d and a file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf with contents

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

> and I get the unity greeter back.