# New to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system

as you might have read, I!m new to Ubuntu 14.04 after have been running Windows XP for a long time. Ihave an Acer Aspire One computer that ran Windows XP for over 5 years, but after the end of Microsoft's support to XP I decided to move to Ubuntu. But after a few days of tests I have realizad that the computer is very slow even being absolutelly empty. It used to be very slow in the last several months with Windows XP too, but I thought that with a new operating system and a brand new hard disk, the problem would be solved. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A hard disk won't necessarily solve the problem of speeding up a computer. You may need to look into upgrading your RAM..

Comment: Impossible to answer with the current wording. Please do a search on AU and/or google for similar topics and read up on the answers on how to diagnose.

Comment: As the abovetwo people said, you'll need to look into other things. You may also want to look into an older distribution of Ubuntu as well - it sounds like your computer is pretty old. Try 12.04 and if that's still slow, maybe try 10.04

Comment: Be more specific about slowness of your computer by keeping in mind factor affecting like processor,ram etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 1):

Acer Aspire One is worst performance with Compiz shell's like as Unity,
Try to use for test some shells. lxde (I think has the best performance for a netbook)

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbIlA.jpg

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rms6j.jpg

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGUMG.jpg

if your network manager doesn't start use `ALT+F2 nm-applet`

Answer (score 0):

Try [XFCE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223536/how-can-i-install-xfce-along-side-unity)!

As per
    http://lifehacker.com/5762081/wtf-desktop-environments-gnome-kde-and-more-explained

```
.....XFCE is designed to be very lightweight, without sacrificing usability. It's
actually very similar to GNOME, so new users probably won't have too much trouble
getting around. It isn't the prettiest, but if you have an old computer (or a
low-powered machine like a netbook), this will make it run faster than any other
operating system will (or than GNOME or KDE will, for that matter).......
```