# Will Ubuntu Be faster In Gnome

Tags: unity

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on My old Pc Having
2GB Ram
Pentium 4 Processor 3.04Ghz
6GB Swap
But still it works very slow like Hell.
If I install Gnome Classic Then It will Be fast Or Not?

Comment: What Desktop you are going to compare with Gnome, what do you have now? Gnome is faster than KDE.

Comment: Bro It is unity now.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Ubuntu with the default Unity desktop.  If you are then in my experience Gnome Classic desktop is significantly faster.

Comment: Related (but probably not a duplicate, unless more information is added to answers there, more answers are posted, or answers from here are merged): [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar), [What is the difference between Ubuntu and its derivatives?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to compare with the Unity desktop? Changing to Gnome Classic will improve it a little. If you want to have a lightweight desktop environment, I suggest trying Xfce (http://www.xfce.org/). This is the default desktop environment for the Xubuntu releases.

You can install it on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

for Ubuntu branding or

the original Xfce desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

(Source: [How can I install XFCE along side unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223536/how-can-i-install-xfce-along-side-unity))

Comment: I suggest LXDE!

Comment: i dont have much internet to download whole xubuntu. if i install it in ubuntu 14.04 n delete unity ..
will it be faster n smooth?

Comment: That is also an option. It depends on what you expect/need from a desktop environment and from your own habits and taste.

Comment: @user311066: You should only install the Xfce desktop using one of the two commands above. You do not even have to remove unity in order to test it, so you will be able to switch back easily if necessary. There should not be a measurable difference with installing Xubuntu with the same setup. After all Xubuntu's main feature is an Ubuntu system with by default XFCE in stead of Unity on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes. But CPU and RAM has nothing to do with it. Unity is expecting 3D to work very good, and I suppose you have some video card without supported 3D. Anyway, instead of Gnome you should better step forward and try Xfce. You will have more features for less resources, without compositing window manager. Consider this.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`

then you will probably find something interesting in compiz, like Static Application Switcher, if needed:

`sudo apt-get install ccsm`

`sudo apt-get install  compiz-plugins-extra`

`ccsm`

Comment: I Have Decided To Install LXDE Environment on Ubuntu 14.04 
..
Does It wll Become Fast?
Or In Order To Make Ot Fast i need To remove unity?

Comment: No need to remove, you can have both, yes,it's faster.