# How install/unistall Xfce on Ubuntu 12.04 without uptade?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, xfce

I would like to know how to install Xfce alongside unity?
I'm running Ubuntu on a 2.66 GHz Intel pentium 4 machine, with 1.50GB RAM.
Is fast really user ubuntu/gnome.
I want very fast without problem in browser.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install XFCE along side unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223536/how-can-i-install-xfce-along-side-unity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two good ways to install Xfce:

- `$ sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`
  Comes with a lot of Xfce applications and Xubuntu branding, this might not be desired though.
- `$ sudo apt-get install xfce4`
  Just Xfce and no Xubuntu branding.

After you have installed Xfce, log out of Unity. Next to your name on the logon screen is a button, which when pressed will allow you to select either Unity or Xfce.