# Integrate xfce4

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I uninstalled gnome from my Ubuntu Because of performance issue and installed xfce4.So on booting up I get only terminal , so I type sudo startxfce4 to start GUI .

Everything is ok till here.But when I run xfce4 it runs on root mode and when I click switch users it doesn't show the switch user interface as in most OS and runs as root process.Therefore I can't use chrome because it doesn't run in root mode.

IS there a way to integrate xfce4 in Ubuntu so I don't have to type sudo startxfce4 to start GUI or better is there to switch user in interface after that.Because it doesn't do anything when I click switch user on the power button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install XFCE along side Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223536/how-can-i-install-xfce-along-side-unity)

Comment: on bootup can't you select an xfce session form the gear icon underneath where you type your password?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  How did you remove the Gnome Desktop from your system?  Try running `startxfce4` without `sudo` in front of it.  It could be that you might be missing a Display Manager as well for the start up of the system.  When you removed Gnome it might have removed GDM3 as well.  Try installing LightDM as I believe it is the default Display Manager for Xubuntu (Xfce4) `sudo apt install lightdm` and reboot the computer.

Comment: Without sudo it doesn't startup.Gives an root permission error.Ok I will try to install lightdm and report back