# How do I disable Unity in 13.04?

Tags: unity, compiz, xfce

I'm using Xfce most of the time, but Unity keeps popping up even in my Xfce-Session. So I deactivated the Compiz-Plugin in ccsm, because that worked well in 12.10. But now with 13.04 as soon as I relog into my session, the plugin is active again.

How can I stop this from happening?

I'd rather not remove Unity completely, because maybe I want to try something out once in a while.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you use XFCE, you should use [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org) instead of Ubuntu. It has XFCE preinstalled, so the integration with XFCE is seemless. You can [install Unity in Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111400/can-i-install-unity-aside-with-xfce-and-switch-them-as-i-want) too so you can still access Unity sometimes.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I do have xubuntu-desktop installed and I do select Xubuntu for my session but Unity does get started anyways. The Plugin even gets reactivated when I start ccsm.

Comment: @user158012 No, I didn't mean installing `xubuntu-desktop` on top of regular Ubuntu. I meant reinstalling your system with a special Xubuntu ISO downloaded from Xubuntu.org , which comes preinstalled with `xubuntu-desktop` and XFCE (it doesn't have Unity, but you can install that and `ubuntu-desktop` on top of Xubuntu afterwards if you still want to access it sometimes) and thus haves a seamlessly integrated experience.

Comment: I don't want to appear ungrateful, but there must be another solution to this WITHOUT reinstalling the whole system. There must be something responsible for reactivating the Unity-Plugin. And therefore there must be a way to switch that mechanism off.