# How to install Xfce desktop environment?

Tags: xfce

I have read this post [How do I switch to Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/64241/49666), but it tells me to install `xubuntu-desktop`.

Can I install Xfce (only)? I mean, I don't want to install any application which is not related to Xfce desktop, but becomes dependency of `xubuntu-desktop`, such as abiword, gthumb, etc. What package should I install?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Click here:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or via command line:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

this is what you will get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libstdc++5 libvncserver0 libaio-dev sysstat ksh expat libelf-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  desktop-base exo-utils gtk2-engines-xfce libexo-1-0 libexo-common libgarcon-1-0 libgarcon-common
  libthunarx-2-0 libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util4 libxfconf-0-2
  orage thunar thunar-data thunar-volman xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-appfinder xfce4-mixer
  xfce4-panel xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfce4-utils xfconf xfdesktop4 xfdesktop4-data xfwm4
  xfwm4-themes xscreensaver
Suggested packages:
  thunar-archive-plugin thunar-media-tags-plugin xfprint4 xfce4-goodies fortunes-mod aumix xli
  xloadimage xfishtank xdaliclock qcam streamer
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  desktop-base exo-utils gtk2-engines-xfce libexo-1-0 libexo-common libgarcon-1-0 libgarcon-common
  libthunarx-2-0 libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util4 libxfconf-0-2
  orage thunar thunar-data thunar-volman xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4 xfce4-appfinder xfce4-mixer
  xfce4-panel xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfce4-utils xfconf xfdesktop4 xfdesktop4-data xfwm4
  xfwm4-themes xscreensaver
0 upgraded, 31 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 19.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 80.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

#### once installed log out and choose xfce desktop - log back in

Comment: It told me to remove some package: sabily-grub-artwork :(.

Comment: thats a minor package, I wouldn't worry about that one

Comment: I would also recommend installing the `xubuntu-default-settings` package, which will give you the Xubuntu look and feel, without the extra applications.

Comment: Can I do the same for other desktop environments as well?

Answer (score 11):

xfce can be installed from the terminal by default using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

And to install the goodies (extra programs, plugins, and artwork), the command is:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-goodies
```

Enter your password when prompted.

Enjoy using Xfce!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install xfce-goodies` does not work for me, I think it must be `sudo apt-get install xfce4-goodies`.

Answer (score 1):

On **30/09/2015**

To install latest version of **Xfce 4.12** on Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04:

Open terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Here is the output of commands,

```
ravan@ravan:~$ sudo apt-get install xfce4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
account-plugin-windows-live libupstart1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
desktop-base exo-utils gtk2-engines-xfce libexo-1-0 libexo-common
libexo-helpers libgarcon-1-0 libgarcon-common libjpeg-progs
libjpeg-turbo-progs libkeybinder0 libthunarx-2-0 libtumbler-1-0
libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4ui-common libxfce4ui-utils libxfce4util-bin
libxfce4util-common libxfce4util7 libxfconf-0-2 orage tango-icon-theme
thunar thunar-data thunar-volman tumbler tumbler-common xfce4-appfinder
xfce4-mixer xfce4-notifyd xfce4-panel xfce4-session xfce4-settings
xfce4-volumed xfconf xfdesktop4 xfdesktop4-data xfwm4 xscreensaver
xscreensaver-data xubuntu-icon-theme
Suggested packages:
devhelp sox kdelibs-data thunar-archive-plugin thunar-media-tags-plugin
tumbler-plugins-extra xfce4-goodies xfce4-power-manager gtk3-engines-xfce
fortunes-mod menu xfwm4-themes xfishtank xdaliclock xscreensaver-gl fortune
qcam streamer gdm3 kdm-gdmcompat
Recommended packages:
greybird-gtk-theme
The following NEW packages will be installed:
desktop-base exo-utils gtk2-engines-xfce libexo-1-0 libexo-common
libexo-helpers libgarcon-1-0 libgarcon-common libjpeg-progs
libjpeg-turbo-progs libkeybinder0 libthunarx-2-0 libtumbler-1-0
libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4ui-common libxfce4ui-utils libxfce4util-bin
libxfce4util-common libxfce4util7 libxfconf-0-2 orage tango-icon-theme
thunar thunar-data thunar-volman tumbler tumbler-common xfce4
xfce4-appfinder xfce4-mixer xfce4-notifyd xfce4-panel xfce4-session
xfce4-settings xfce4-volumed xfconf xfdesktop4 xfdesktop4-data xfwm4
xscreensaver xscreensaver-data xubuntu-icon-theme
0 upgraded, 42 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 19.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 69.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

To uninstall PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the command-line, but you can also install Xfce from Synaptic, just type in "xfce4" in the search bar, select everything related to Xfce, and then click "Apply" to install.