# 12.10 very, very, slow on Asus eePc

Tags: 12.10

Just finished installing 12.10 on Asus eePC 101HA. It is so slow that it is almost unusable.
Installation was automatic, no particular changes, and already updated software.

Could you please give me a hint on what to do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable low graphics mode in Unity (1). To do that you need to edit (or create) the file `~/.xprofile` and add this at the bottom:

```
export UNITY_LOW_GFX_MODE=1
```

Save, logout, login and see if it makes any difference. In the case it didn't help at all or it gives you some problem, you can just delete the text you added to `.xprofile`.

Also you can try to install a lightweight window manager like OpenBox or XFCE(2).

Hope this helps.

Sources:

1. [Answer to "How do I enable llvmpipe rendering in Unity?"](https://askubuntu.com/a/202176/33871)
2. [How to install Xfce desktop environment?](https://askubuntu.com/q/116602/33871)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead of Ubuntu for this model as the requirements for graphics are far less so the CPU would get some cycles for other work. Most important install Jupiter and Jupiter eeepc utilities and that would get the SHE engine running giving you a performance and battery boost.