# Enabling a multi display desktop completely broke Gnome Shell. Help?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, monitor, ati

I've been trying to get my dual desktops working on Ubuntu for a while. I previously had them as one large desktop, but that was incredibly slow for some reason. I tried to switch them to multi display desktop on the AMD Catalyst Control Center.

Here's what I get after restarting and logging in:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbdHm.png

I'm running an AMD Quad Core A6, AMD Radeon 6540G2 GPU, 16GB Ram. Ubuntu 12.04
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing the AMD variation of the NVIDIA second monitor kluge, see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1002641).

I got a limited use of a second monitor by [dropping Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151056/how-to-downgrade-compiz-to-0-8-6-in-ubuntu-12-04/151425#151425) and [switching to Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64241/how-do-i-switch-to-xubuntu).

BTW while Unity probably will be great for the casual computer user, it severly restricts the way I work.  Dropping it was a huge step forward.

BTW I really like Xubuntu and will not go back to Gnome.

BTW [Gnome Classic still produces duplicate panel icons](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/1002645) after removing Unity.

Here are screenshots of screen0 and screen1...
[image] [image]

*Open in a separate window/tab for full size: screen0->2560x1600; screen1->1440x900*