# How to downgrade Compiz to 0.8.6 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, compiz, downgrade

Is there a safe way to **downgrade Compiz to 0.8.6** in Ubuntu 12.04? I don't want to use Unity anymore and due to bug [#862430](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/862430) and bug [#933776](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/933776) Compiz is unusable for me.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running 12.04 and using compiz version 1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1 without any problems.  However when I had Unity it was a nightmare.

My solution, since I was upgrading from 10.10, was switch to Xubuntu 10.10 and to remove Unity at each upgrade step.

As a result, I ended up at Xubuntu 12.04 using 1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1 with very nice
results.

I didn't have to remove Unity when upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04.

You may only have to remove Unity to get where you want to go.

I used the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity) for guidance.

---

Here are the suggested steps for 12.04...

### For 12.04

Remove the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications gir1.2-unity-5.0 unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu libindicator7 indicator-application indicator-datetime indicator-messages libnux-2.0-0 nux-tools libunity-misc4 unity-2d-common
```

`syslinux-legacy` will be installed, but this can be safely ignored.

Note: After removing Unity using the above described method, provided LightDM hasn't been otherwise removed, you'll still be greeted with the LightDM desktop manager upon rebooting into Ubuntu. But with Unity removed, LightDM won't have any desktops to manage, and so attempting to log in from LightDM will result in an error message. From LightDM, you can use "CTRL+ALT+F1" to exit into a terminal, from which you can install a new desktop environment, if desired.  For example, "sudo apt-get install gnome-core" can be used to install the Gnome Desktop Environment from the terminal, or "sudo apt-get install lxde" can be used to install LXDE from the terminal, etc. You will be given a choice between "lightdm" and "gdm" desktop managers during the desktop installation process. Selecting "lightdm" works with both the Gnome Desktop Environment and LXDE.

---

**Note:** When I ran the `sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d ....` it failed saying it could not find a package. (`nuxtools` for 11.10).  What I did was edit the `sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d ....` removing the package apt-get could not find, and it worked.

Here is the result...! [image: A workspace using cube and 3D windows in 12.04]

Comment: I still get the "flicker" but the usefulness of the cube & 3D windows outweighs the inconvenience.  Since the bug is affecting 295 people - it's pretty safe to assume it will be fixed soon.

Comment: The scale issue with showing all windows from all workspaces is fixed in 12.10. However, there are doubts it ever will be fixed for 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

to downgrade a package

```
sudo apt-get install <package_name=version>
```

in the version place you have to place whats the version you want to install .

Comment: Sure, but compiz 0.8.6 ist not in the repositories anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary fix for who want to use **compiz 0.9.8.**

(Do this at your own risk.)

Login to Gnome 3 session, and completely remove compiz. Then hit the following commands on the terminal.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vanvugt/compiz-preproposed
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade

Compiz shuld work **better** when you log back to Unity or Gnome Classic.