# Receiving "Please insert CD error" when trying to install xubuntu desktop in 12.04

Tags: installation, software-sources, xubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.
I want to install xfce desktop. When I tried to install Xubuntu desktop, I got the  following message.

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop

Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120817.3)'
in the drive '/cdrom/' and press enter
```

I didn't know why I'm getting this error, and also I don't have CD drive. I installed Ubuntu using usb.

Please let me know how to install xubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 5):

In the ubuntu software center, the edit tab also has a selection for software sources. If you were to uncheck the cdrom in the window at the bottom, your problem may be solved.

Answer (score 1):

you have to open the **"Software Sources"**, which you will find using the Unity dash.

To remove the CD sources you have to uncheck all sources in **"Installable from CD-ROM/DVD"**.

after this is done just update the sources again and try to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a place in Synaptic where you can uncheck the CD drive as a source.  Not sure if this will solve your problem.

You've interchanged xubuntu and lubuntu in your references.  They aren't the same (hope this helps)

Answer (score -2):

It's been asked before, [How do I switch to Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64241/how-do-i-switch-to-xubuntu)

.. you gotta have an internet connection.

**Edit**: Judging by the other answers in the thread, it would seem that I had made a mistake with stating about the internet connection and that the case here is that of preferences; @Argusvision tnx again for the guidelines!..:)

PS. From [Frequently Asked Questions](https://askubuntu.com/faq): 'If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong. Provide better answers of your own. Best of all — edit and improve the existing questions and answers!' -- so, in translation, please try not to just slam my attempts at **helping** because it's not like I'm posting here out of vanity, ya know (squashing the issue, I was just really disappointed to find out that I got voted down when trying to provide a helpful answer).

Comment: Somebody just gave me a negative rating on my answer, why in the world would you do that? o_0

Comment: I didn't give you that rating, so I don't know exactly. However, it's probably because you stated "You gotta have an internet connection." That statement is both untrue and not particularly helpful. If you would like to get the rep points back you can delete the answer.

Comment: You could also try editing the answer to be more accurate and productive.

Comment: Your answer wasn't really an answer for the problem. Check the voted answer

Comment: Thanks for the info guys!..:)

@Argusvision "you gotta have an internet connection" - otherwise you will be asked for a source cd/usb/whatever - isn't it? I really can't see anything wrong with that, or my answer.

Comment: I would suggest adding a comment under the question that asks for clarification.  
Ex: "Do you have an internet connection? If I understand it correctly, not having an internet connection will prompt it to check for a CD." Or something along those lines.

Comment: I forgot. Commenting directly to a question requires 50+. Sorry.
And I mean that sincerely, not a dig. (I just re-read that in a "mean girl" voice... :)  )

Comment: @Argusvision Awesome, that's what I've been looking for; tnx. (lol, cool)

Comment: Since this is becoming a conversation, we need to cut short here. Just make sure you check out the FAQ at http://askubuntu.com/faq