# How to install build-essential without the CD/DVD?

Tags: 12.04, development, tools

I am trying to install the build-essential package per the instructions located here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers

I get this error when I use the command `apt-get install build-essential`:

```
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120817.3)'
in the drive '/cdrom/' and press enter
```

When attempting to install the package through the Ubuntu Software Center, I get the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMIx5.png

Is there any way to install the package online only?

Comment: Probably the same "problem": http://askubuntu.com/questions/202558/receiving-please-insert-cd-error-when-trying-to-install-xubuntu-desktop-in-12/202567#202567

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, this solved my problem. If you wish to post your comment as an answer I'll be glad to rate it as the answer to this question.

Comment: just rate the answer on the other question, which was also mine : )

Comment: Haha I noticed this. However my reputation is too low (1 point) to do this. I'll just answer my own question, unless you'd like to put it in different words. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **Ubuntu Software Center** select **Edit -> Software Sources...** from the menu bar. Under the first tab called **Ubuntu Software**, deselect the **Installable from CD-ROM/DVD** source, then close the window.

This answer is taken from Stefan [Receiving "Please insert CD error" when trying to install xubuntu desktop in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202558/receiving-please-insert-cd-error-when-trying-to-install-xubuntu-desktop-in-12/202567#202567)